# Error in file uploading in perl

Tags: file, upload, cgi, perl

i am trying to upload a file in perl, the file is getting created when i check it on ftp server, but the size is 0 there, i wonder why is it happening, i searched and tried a lot but couldn't solve this, could you please help me?

Here's the code which i am using :

```
    enter code here
    use CGI; 
    my $query = new CGI; 
    my $upload_dir = "/home/public_html/upload/avatars";
    my $filename = $ses->getUserId."_".$query->param("profile_avatar");
    my $org_filename = $ses->getUserId."_".$f->{profile_avatar};
    my ($name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ($org_filename , qr/\.[^\.]+$/ ); 
    $filename = $name . $extension;
    my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";  
    $filename =~ tr/ /_/; 
    $filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;
    $filename =~ s/.*[\/\\](.*)/$1/;
    my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("profile_avatar"); 
    open(UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename") or $ses->message("$!");
    binmode UPLOADFILE;
    while (<$upload_filehandle>)
    {
        print UPLOADFILE;
    }
    close UPLOADFILE;
```

In this variable ($upload_filehandle) i am getting blank meaning nothing, i don't know why is it happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a subroutine that I know works...

I have a CGI like yours that calls it with the parameter, $query->param("profile_avatar");

```
sub upload_bin_file
{
my ($ufile) = @_;
my $ufilename = "\L$ufile";  #Force filename to be lower case
$ufilename = ~s/\\/\//g;     # Convert backslashes to forward slashes

my @dirs = split(/\//, $ufilename);    # SPlit the filename by the paths(s)
my $dfile = "$UFILE_DIR/$dirs[$#dirs]";  # This takes just the filename part
print "File uploaded to [$dfile]<BR>\n"; # Optional debug statement

open(DEST,">$dfile") or die "[F] Upload server: Could not open $dfile: $!";
binmode(DEST);
binmode($ufile);
my @src_content=<$ufile>;
print DEST @src_content;
close($ufile);
close(DEST);

$dfile; #Return the name of the file that we uploaded
}
```

I'm not sure if the binmode of the incoming file is the answer, or stripping the path from the filename. You can try it and see :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and wasted a lot of time trying to figure it out. In my case the solution was simple, but not at all obvious. I'm making a note of it in case people find it helpful.

It turns out CGI.pm (3.5.2) creates temp files in /usr/tmp/

For reasons I'm not really sure of, my machine had >480 of these sitting around; some of them quite large. In principle these are supposed to be deleted on exit but were apparently still around. When I deleted them, things just started to work again with the original script(s), just like before.

Unfortunately I cleaned tmp/ up on a lark, without really looking around, using 'rm /usr/tmp/CGI*'. It's possible that tmp/ was completely filled up and I just happened to free up some space. But perl (v5.14.2) was getting what it thought was a perfectly ok file handle. And nobody noticed or otherwise complained (it's a server so you'd think they should have).

Useful code for along the way:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\012\012";
print "<html><head></head><body>\012";
print "<b>Below is an EXACT echo of what your browser sent:</b>\012<hr>";
print "<pre>\012";
while (<STDIN>) {
  s/>/&gt;/g;
  s/</&lt;/g;
  print $_;
}

print "</pre>\012";
print "</body></html>\012";
```